# Unit test not showing up in SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, nunit, opencover

Using Jenkins I am trying to pass the result of the Nunit task and the OpenCover task to SonarQube.

SonarQube displays properly the test coverage but there is no trace of unit test results.

Here is what I do :

1. Build Visual Studio project with MSBuild
2. Batch windows for opencover via nunit
3. Launch SonarQube scanner
   Batch windows for deployement

Here is my actual properties  for the Sonar Scanner task:

```
sonar.projectKey=FC
sonar.projectName=FC
sonar.projectVersion=%SVN_REVISION%
sonar.sources=src
sonar.binaries=build
sonar.exclusions=src/FC.Test/**/*.*
sonar.tests=src/FC.Test
sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=TestResult.xml
sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=reports/opencovertests.xml
```

I'm using SonarQube 5.6, Jenkins 2.10, SonarQube plugin 2.4.3, OpenCover 4.5 and Nunit 2.6.4

Is there any known problems (compatibility issues...) ?

Note that I tryed to wrap my process with the Prepare and Terminate Sonar analysis tasks but it systematicaly deletes the coverage panel. So i removed it.

EDIT 2017

I stopped doing this way. I understood that the good way to do this was using the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild which is integrated at the Jenkins's plugin.
The coverage panel was not shown because i didn't configure my quality profiles properly.

But...

I still don't have my tests' result in Sonar.

I checked the absolute path of my report and its parsing by sonarQube : "`INFO: Sensor C# Unit Test Results Import [csharp] (done) | time=25ms`". I also tryed with a .nunit file. I saw that apply a filter to opencover could help, so I did.

Do you have a clue?

Answer (score 2):

Scanning C# projects requires to use the Sonar Scanner for MSBuild and follow a specific 3 steps process which I guess you don't follow for now. See doc about the 3 steps process at: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild and http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/From+Jenkins

Your properties look correct. Yet they shall not be provided in a sonar properties file but instead in the command line arguments of the **MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin** step, for example:

```
MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin <allMandatoryParameters> /d:sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=TestResult.xml /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=reports\opencovertests.xml
```

Olivier

Comment: I realised that my first post was to blurry. I added details. Please have a look.